# How do i specify which Firefox Profile to use thru perl based Selenium script?

Tags: perl, firefox, selenium

I am using the following lines in a perl script to open a browser using Selenium. :

```
my $sel = Test::WWW::Selenium->new( host => "localhost", 
                                port => 4444, 
                                browser => "*firefox", 
                                browser_url => "https://$ARGV[0]/" );
```

Here in browser => "*firefox",  how do i specify a specific firefox Profile that should be opened. I've already tried :

```
browser => "*firefox C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe -P \"Selenium\" "
```

and

```
browser => " C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe -P \"Selenium\" ".
```

I also tired creating a Firefox shortcut with its target as

```
C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe -P "Selenium"
```

and then giving the path of this shortcut as the browser. I havent got anything to work so far. 
Am i doing something wrong here. Or is there any other way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

The [WWW::Selenium](http://search.cpan.org/~mattp/Test-WWW-Selenium-1.36/lib/WWW/Selenium.pm) documentation indicates that it uses a different profile to the main firefox profile already:

> Automatically launch a new Firefox process using a custom Firefox profile. This profile will be automatically configured to use the Selenium Server as a proxy and to have all annoying prompts ("save your password?" "forms are insecure" "make Firefox your default browser?" disabled.

If you load that profile in your main browser then you can customise the profile (such as accepting self signed certificates).

Answer (score 0):

If you have Firefox already running, you need to add a "--no-remote" option. Without it, Firefox will open a new window for the same browser process.

Comment: i dont have firefox running.

Comment: @user2318314 -- In that case, all I can suggest is go through the log file that Selenium RC writes. It usually has something about building profiles. Also, run the firefox command directly and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

As Matthew says, WWW::Selenium opens a custom profile when you use the *firefox option

Instead of editting the existing one, I made a new profile, set it up how I wanted it and then copied that into the .jar file in the customProfileDirCUSTFFCHROME folder.

The only tricky bit is that you need to also include the extensions that were originally in the customProfileDirCUSTFFCHROME folder that allows selenium to control firefox.

Comment: I have the same problem as the OP. When running the Selenium server, where can I find the "customProfileDirCUSTFFCHROME" folder?